# Low-level exception handling in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

How can I use exception handling in Rails? Currently I have done following.

In each controller method I have added

```
begin
  <myCode>
rescue
  <exception handler>
```

But I think with Rails I should be able to define an exception handler method in Application controller and catch all the exceptions from there, without handling them from each method.

I have used 'rescue_action_in_public' in my application controller, but when I given a wrong database name in config/database.yml and load the application, it doesn't catch those exceptions.

## My questions are

1 - Is it a recompilation practice to have one exception handler in the application controller and catch the exceptions ? If not, what is the standard way ?

2 - How can I handle the Exceptions like Databse not found, doesn't have permission to view table fields, etc kind of low level exceptions

I'm riding on Rails 3 and I have some projects in Rails 2.3.8 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With according to Advanced Rails Recipes book by PragProg, the general exception handling is the good approach.
 **rescue_action** (all environments), and **rescue_action_in_public** (production) are using to caught any exceptions in abstract controller class. So you do it right way.

Boot application happens before the controllers are loaded, so you can't handle **database.yml** over there. If you still need to do it, put an initializer ruby file to check that the file exist and a valid, then initialize AR::Base connection to perform *DESC table* for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3 you can use `rescue_from` in your ApplicationController. If the exceptions you want to catch are at a lower level then you can configure a Rack Middleware layer will allow you to catch exceptions that the controller does not have access to. This is how Hoptoad works. I recently released a rails 3 gem that will catch common exceptions using rescue_from and provide well defined http status codes and error responses for html, json and xml.  This may or may not fit your needs. https://github.com/voomify/egregious